# Using AsyncTask with JSON Request from Database

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, progressdialog, runnable

I am trying to parse some values from my Database in Android Studio, using JSON parsing. I want to use an AsyncTask and run it on a BackgroundThread, as it appears to be to much to run on the mainthread.

I am using the data from my database in a mapsactivity, using google maps to place markers(may be relevant).

The problem is that even though i am trying to use an AsyncTask (i am still new to Android), it still tells me this in the console:

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Here is my code for my AsyncTask:

```
public class GetMarkers extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllMarkersActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading markers...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();
                            while( keys.hasNext() )
                            {
                                String key = keys.next();
                                if(!key.equals("success")){   // or use this if your keys are always in digits form.. if(TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(key))
                                    Log.v("category key", key);

                                    JSONObject innerJObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject(key);

                                    String lat_str = innerJObject.getString("lat");
                                    double lat = 0.0, lng = 0.0;

                                    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(lat_str) &&      TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(lat_str))
                                        lat = Double.parseDouble(lat_str);

                                    String lng_str = innerJObject.getString("lng");

                                    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(lng_str) && TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(lng_str))
                                        lng = Double.parseDouble(lng_str);

                                    LatLng Mplace = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                                    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(Mplace).title("Marker").snippet("Snippet:" + "0");
                                    mMap.addMarker(marker);

                                }
                            }





                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.i("RESPONSE:", "[" + response + "]");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    }

                };

                MarkerRequest markerRequest = new MarkerRequest(responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(AllMarkersActivity.this);
                queue.add(markerRequest);

            }
        });


        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once got all details
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }


}
```

When i then want to execute i merely use:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    new GetMarkers().execute();
```

However for some reason, the progress dialog never shows up when i open my mapsactivity, and it gives me the 33 skipped frames "error".

Any help is much appreciated!

Please answer with an example, still learning! :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get rid of `runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {`

The point of `doInBackground` here is so it does NOT run on the UI-thread.

Your UI stuff should be taking place in `onPostExecute`

and technically, since you are using `Response.Listener<String> responseListener`, you shouldn't need to run this inside an `AsyncTask`

`public void onResponse` behaves like the `onPostExecute`